# How to apply same code to new worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to duplicate the code below so it applies to every new sheet.

I have to manually change the code to the new sheet's name. I found loops but that coding didn't work for me. I am trying to create a stop watch function for billing hours.

I can copy sheets and create a copy, but then none of the functions work in the new sheet it says

> Run-Time Error 1004: select method of Range class failed

and stops on this line:

```
Sheets("Client").Range("B" & iRow).Select
```

```vb
Sub Intialize()

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = Sheets("Client").Range("F" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Code to Validate
    If Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).Value = "" Then
        Sheets("Client").Range("A" & iRow).Value = Format([Today()], "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    End If

End Sub
```

```vb
Sub Start_Time()

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = Sheets("Client").Range("F" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'Code to Validate
    If Sheets("Client").Range("B" & iRow).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Task Name from the drop down.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Task Name Blank"
        Sheets("Client").Range("B" & iRow).Select
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Start Time is aleady captured for the selected Task."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).Value = [Now()]
        Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End If

End Sub
```

```vb
Sub End_Time()

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = Sheets("Client").Range("F" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'Code to Validate
    If Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Start Time has not been captured for this task."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Sheets("Client").Range("E" & iRow).Value = [Now()]
        Sheets("Client").Range("E" & iRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
        Sheets("Client").Range("F" & iRow).Value = Sheets("Client").Range("E" & iRow).Value - Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).Value
        Sheets("Client").Range("F" & iRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    End If

    Call Intialize

End Sub
```

Comment: So, you got "Error 1004", did it say something else? I can guess what it said, but that is something you should put in your question. Always when you get some errors, copy the complete error message into your question, and also what exactly you were doing when the error was given.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! Yes, that is the error code I got it. Sorry about that. Specifically, it says "Run-Time Error 1004: select method of Range class failed"

Comment: It stops on this one:  Sheets("Client").Range("B" & iRow).Select

Comment: **Side note:** your `Exit Sub`s in `Start_Time()` are doing absolutely nothing and the one in `End_Time()` can easily be removed by moving `Call Intialize` inside the `Else` block.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code is placed (Module vs Worksheet, Same Workbook as the Data, etc). Likely your issue is that ranges can only be selected if that worksheet is active but you should also be careful about calling code that doesn't explicitly qualify what workbook. So columns are A = Date, B = Task, D = Start Time, E = End Time, F = Duration?

Comment: Thank you @MarkBalhoff! I removed the exit sub and moved the Call Initialize inside the else block. Everything, I believe is in the same workbook. I only have one worksheet. Yes, you have the columns correct. Ideally, I just want to duplicate this worksheet but I am unable to figure out how...

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you said:
1 Need to copy a single Sheet
2 Apply a code to that sheet, whatever the name
3 You will create (copy) several sheet.

Here is my code.

(Paste everything in a normal module)

```
Option Explicit
    
    Const A = 1
    Const B = 2
    Const D = 4
    Const E = 5
    Const F = 6
    Const L = 1048576 'Excel.Application.Rows.Count   

'With this you can check if you can copy the sheet
'and also, return that sheet you already checked,
'no matter the name of that sheet.

Private Function SetSheet(sht As Worksheet) As Worksheet

    'This function validate if the sheet is one that you need to copy
    'Assuming the first sheets of the book are used to:
    '
    'Parameters         1
    'Main               2
    'Other...           3
    
    If sht.Index >= 4 Then 'Here is where (Sheet #4 and so on) begins...
        Set SetSheet = sht
    Else
        'Message or do nothing...
        End
    End If
End Function

Sub Intialize()
'    You can uncomment this DIM vars but
'    need to comment the const above.

'    Dim F: F = Range("F1").Column
'    Dim D: D = Range("D1").Column
'    Dim A: A = Range("A1").Column
'    Dim L: L = Application.Rows.Count

    Dim ActSht As Worksheet: Set ActSht = SetSheet(ActiveSheet)
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = ActSht.Range(Cells(L, F), Cells(L, F)).End(xlUp).Row

'    Code to Validate

    If ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, D), Cells(iRow, D)).Value = "" Then
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, A), Cells(iRow, A)).Value = Format([Today()], "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    End If
End Sub

Sub Start_Time()
'    Dim B: B = Range("B1").Column
'    Dim F: F = Range("F1").Column
'    Dim D: D = Range("D1").Column
'    Dim L: L = Application.Rows.Count

    Dim ActSht As Worksheet: Set ActSht = SetSheet(ActiveSheet)
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = ActSht.Range(Cells(L, F), Cells(L, F)).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
'    Code to Validate

    If ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, B), Cells(iRow, B)).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Task Name from the drop down.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Task Name Blank"
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, B), Cells(iRow, B)).Select
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, D), Cells(iRow, D)).Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Start Time is aleady captured for the selected Task."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, D), Cells(iRow, D)).Value = [Now()]
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, D), Cells(iRow, D)).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End If
End Sub

Sub End_Time()
'    Dim D: D = Range("D1").Column
'    Dim F: F = Range("F1").Column
'    Dim E: E = Range("E1").Column
'    Dim L: L = Application.Rows.Count

    Dim ActSht As Worksheet: Set ActSht = SetSheet(ActiveSheet)
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = ActSht.Range(Cells(L, F), Cells(L, F)).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'    Code to Validate
    If ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, D), Cells(iRow, D)).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Start Time has not been captured for this task."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, E), Cells(iRow, E)).Value = [Now()]
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, E), Cells(iRow, E)).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
        
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, F), Cells(iRow, F)).Value = Sheets("Client").Range("E" & iRow).Value - Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).Value
        ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, F), Cells(iRow, F)).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    End If
    Call Intialize
End Sub
```

Asummtions:
1 You call one or several of this sub-rutines from the original worksheet.

Note:
It is better not to use hardcoded this way `Sheets("Client").Range("D" & iRow).Value` because when you need to debug... It hurts! That is why I do prefer `ActSht.Range(Cells(iRow, D), Cells(iRow, D)).Value` and you can control a single var above all the code.

Comment: Thank you so much @ElbertVillarreal! I just tried to copy and paste into a new module and I assigned the new macros. But the timer function no longer works. It does bring up an error code but not for the main code. It says there's an issue with the first line of this code. The private sub line.  

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'Fill the Date and Name in next blank row
    'Call Intialize

End Sub

Comment: Well, it is important to share the complete code to help you, because, your talking about another part of the code `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. This line of code comes into `Thisworkbook` (Normally called). And the message (I assume) `Fill the Date and Name in next blank row` is part of that private function.

Comment: Please share that part of the code or the whole code if is possible, into the question. And also share the error (a screenshot), to see why this happens.

Comment: (1) Remmenber the `Private Function SetSheet(sht As Worksheet) As Worksheet` could be public this way `Function SetSheet(sht As Worksheet) As Worksheet` and that's it

Comment: (1) Remmenber the `Private Function SetSheet(sht As Worksheet) As Worksheet` could be public this way `Function SetSheet(sht As Worksheet) As Worksheet` and that's it
(2) If the Function SetSheet hit a index sheet under the number you define as initial sheet to copy, the code will end with no warnings, and all the code in the workbook. 
(3) Which is the "Timer" Function? Is importante to share that function to help you.